# mysql | count records grouped by time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I have a code to get array of dates (This month - 12):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 11; $i++) {
    $months[] = date("Y-m", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
}
```

To get records from DB by specified month I can use the code below:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `#__records` WHERE MONTH(date)=1 AND YEAR(date)=2010';
```

Hot to create my request to get data by each month?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 11; $i++) {
    $months[] = date("Y-m", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
}

$count = sizeof($months);

 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
 {
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM `#__records` WHERE MONTH(date)='".$months[$i]."' AND YEAR(date)=2010';
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result)
{
$data_array = array();
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($data)
    {
        $data_array[] = array($data['id']);
    }
}
}
print_r($data_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly in SQL with an appropriate `GROUP BY` query.

The trick is this little expression.  Given any DATE or DATETIME`, it yields the first day of the month.

```
DATE(DATE_FORMAT(datevalue, '%Y-%m-01'))
```

The query uses that formula a lot to figure things out.

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS idcount,
       DATE(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01')) AS month_beginning
  FROM table
 WHERE date >= DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01')) - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
   AND date <  DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01')) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  GROUP BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01'))
  ORDER BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01'))
```

This gives back one row for each of the most recent twelve months.

Here's a more extensive writeup on this kind of summary query.  http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

Comment: What do you get if you try `SELECT id, DATE(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01')) FROM table` ? Do you get the right start-of-month date? Also, maybe you should include the column name `date` in backticks, because it's a reserved word.